# Total insertion and deletion time

Tags: java, linked-list, time-complexity

The Professor: your program needs to print total insertion time and total deletion time for all the insertion and deletion scenarios.

We need to use it in a Circular singly and Doubly linked list.
I was wondering how I can find the time!!!
Thanks

This is my output.

Adding node 100 at start
Adding node 1000 at start
Adding node 10000 at start
Adding node 100000 at start
Circular Linked List: <-> 100000 <-> 10000 <-> 1000 <-> 100

deleting node 100000 from start
Circular Linked List: <-> 10000 <-> 1000 <-> 100

Node 100000 is added at the end of the list
Circular Linked List: <-> 10000 <-> 1000 <-> 100 <-> 100000
Size of linked list: 4
Element at 2nd position: 1000

Comment: That's good to know, but do you have a question?

Comment: I was wondering How I can find the insertion time.

Comment: A quick-and-dirty way to obtain the current time in **milliseconds** is  `long t = (new java.util.Date()).getTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to record time at start and end of the operation. Difference between end time and start time is the time taken by the operation.

At operation start:

```
start_time = current_time
```

At operation end:

```
end_time = current_time
exec_time = end_time - start_time
```

Use appropriate time api based on programming language being used.